# Why are some of the variables in POJO equal to null after converting JSON RESTful Webservice?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I am consuming a RESTful webservice that returns a `JSON` payload. I can successfully consume the RESTful webservice and manage to populate some of the `POJO` attributes with `JSON` data. However, some other attributes are null when they are supposed to contain a value. How can I ensure that there are no more nulls?

I have defined 4 POJO classes. I have so far debugged by systematically by testing the variables for each class. This is using Springboot 2.2.0 and Jackson-databind.

The JSON schema I am trying to consume:

```
{
   "items":[
      {
         "timestamp":"2019-09-18T16:42:54.203Z",
         "carpark_data":[
            {
               "total_lots":"string",
               "lot_type":"string",
               "lots_available":"string"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

For the above, I defined 4 classes:

```
public class Response {
@JsonProperty
private List<items> i;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class items {
private String timestamp;
private List<carpark_data> cpd;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class carpark_data {
private List<carpark_info> cpi;
private String carpark_number;
private String update_datetime;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class carpark_info {
private int total_lots;
private String lot_type;
private int lots_available;
```

When I run the below in Spring boot Main: I get null. Is my POJO modeling OK?

```
Response resp = restTemplate.getForObject("")
c = resp.getItems().get(0).getCarpark_data().get(0);
log.info("The last update time for the car park data = " +     
c.getUpdateDatetime());
```

Comment: Probably because the POJO attribute name do not match the JSON attribute name. For example, if you have a carpark_data attribute in your JSON, you need an attribute with the same name in your POJO, at the same level.

Comment: Thanks @DiegoVictordeJesus. I am working on it. I see my mistakes.

Comment: Thank you @DiegoVictordeJesus! I corrected the mismatches. Now everything is working. Big lesson learnt. I feel more confident with working with this stuff. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not fit to `JSON` payload. If we assume that `JSON` payload has a structure like below:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "timestamp": "2019-09-18T16:42:54.203Z",
      "carpark_data": [
        {
          "total_lots": "1000",
          "lot_type": "string",
          "lots_available": "800"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

We can deserialise it as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Response response = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Response.class);

        System.out.println(response.getItems().get(0).getData().get(0));
    }
}

class Response {
    private List<Item> items;

    //getters, setters, toString
}

class Item {
    private String timestamp;

    @JsonProperty("carpark_data")
    private List<CarParkInfo> data;

    //getters, setters, toString
}

class CarParkInfo {

    @JsonProperty("total_lots")
    private int totalLots;

    @JsonProperty("lot_type")
    private String lotType;

    @JsonProperty("lots_available")
    private int lotsAvailable;

    //getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
CarParkInfo{totalLots=1000, lotType='string', lotsAvailable=800}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I can see where I went wrong. I am busy working through it and making corrections.

Comment: Thanks again @Michal Ziober. 
I seem to have given you an outdated schema. I looked at your proposed solution and applied it to the updated schema. As a result, you have helped me learn how to model the JSON data. I will be doing this for a couple more APIs that I need for my research work and apply what you have helped me with. Thank you.

Comment: @codeprojector, I'm glad it works for you and I could help. You can also try to use [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) online tool which creates `POJO` model for given `JSON` payload. It can even generate `Jackson` annotations. It could be a good start for a big schema.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you find the solution.

It is in POJO, you need to check the fieldName and object structure.
Seeing the Json above, your response model returns list of items and in each item you have list of carpark_data. So, basic modelling should be like this. And you can include respective setter and getter.

```
public class Response {
@JsonProperty
private List<items> items;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class items {
private String timestamp;
private List<carpark_data> carpark_data;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class carpark_data {
private int total_lots;
private String lot_type;
private int lots_available;
}
```

You need to have fields name in POJO class same in the Json response or you can set JsonProperty for that field. Like this

```
@JsonProperty("items")
private List<items> i;
@JsonProperty("carpark_data")
private List<carpark_data> cpd;
```